# How to append value from object in JQuery using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using AJAX to return my object. I did a `console.log(obj)` and my object seems perfect. This is how it looks in my console log :

```
[{"first_name":"jeremiah", "last_name":"test"}, {"first_name":"jay", "last_name":"grens"}]
```

However, when I come to append each `first_name` and each `last_name` to a specific `div`, I can't make it work. This is how my Ajax looks like :

```
$('#search_contact').keyup(function() {
var keys = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'contacts/search',
    data: {'keys':keys},
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        $('#contacts tbody').html('');
        $.each(res, function(i, val) {
            $('#contacts tbody').append('<tr><td>'+first_name+'</td><td>'+last_name+'</td></tr>');
        });
    }
});
});
```

When I do this, my #contacts `tbody` is empty and I get this error in my console log :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '926' in (my full obj...)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing you this error?

Comment: Finally found it :) Thank you anyway Terry!

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'contacts/search',
    data: {'keys':keys},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        $('#contacts tbody').html('');
        $.each(res, function(i, val) {
            $('#contacts tbody').append('<tr><td>'+val.first_name+'</td><td>'+val.last_name+'</td></tr>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I still get an error :( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '926' in

Comment: The `keys` should be a string.

Comment: My variable keys is already a string. I get the value of an input with keyup event.

Answer (score 2):

To get `first_name` using `$.each`, you need to use the `0` index like

```
$(this)[0]['first_name']
```

or the `val` parameter you were passing into the callback function like

```
val['first_name']
```

See it working both ways in the snippet

```js
var test = [{"first_name":"jeremiah", "last_name":"test"}, {"first_name":"jay", "last_name":"grens"}];

$.each(test, function(i, val){
       $('body').append('<div>'
                        +$(this)[0]['first_name']+'</div><div>'
                        +val['last_name']+'</div>');
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**

Like others have mentioned, you need to use `$.parseJSON` to avoid the exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search...
```

or you can set `dataType: 'json'` to automatically parse the response to `JSON`

Comment: I tried your solution but I still get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '926' in

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it, thanks to you guys to point me to the right way.

```
$('#search_contact').keyup(function() {
var keys = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'contacts/search',
    data: {'keys':keys},
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        $('#contacts tbody').html('');
        var res = $.parseJSON(res);
        $.each(res, function(key, val) {
            console.log(val['first_name']);
        });
    }
});
});
```

As you can see, I added a new line before $.each to convert a string thats come from php script to a json array.

Comment: You don't need to parse json if you send a json object.

Comment: MathieuBoisjoli, @RomanC is right, just use the ajax call like in his answerh with dataType:'json' and you wont have to use $.parseJSON